# X11 Forwarding Issues - Wrong Authentication

Tags: ssh, x11

I am trying to configure X11 forwarding through SSH on my home server.

The server is running Debian Jessie (hostname `moonraker`) in a headless configuration.

My client is running OS X 10.10. I have used X11 forwarding on other servers before on this client, so I don't think the issue is with my Mac.

The exact error message I recieve after running `xclock` is:

```
X11 connection rejected because of wrong authentication.
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0
```

After some googling, I have verified the following:

1) `$ ls -lA ~/.Xauthority`

```
-rw------- 1 ssunder ssunder 55 Sep 21 21:53 /home/ssunder/.Xauthority
```

2) `$ grep X11 /etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost yes
```

3) My client's `~/.ssh/config` contains:

```
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

4) `$ xauth list`

```
moonraker/unix:10  MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1  d7e2e4a8c5aa4430bfcc2abb436940d2
```

5) Running `sshd` with debug level 2: `# cat /var/log/auth.log | grep sshd | tail -n 100 | less`

```
Sep 21 22:19:57 moonraker sshd[20089]: debug1: X11 connection requested.
Sep 21 22:19:57 moonraker sshd[20089]: debug2: fd 10 setting TCP_NODELAY
Sep 21 22:19:57 moonraker sshd[20089]: debug2: fd 10 setting O_NONBLOCK
Sep 21 22:19:57 moonraker sshd[20089]: debug1: channel 3: new [X11 connection from ::1 port 34632]
Sep 21 22:19:57 moonraker sshd[20089]: debug2: channel 3: open confirm rwindow 2097152 rmax 16384
Sep 21 22:19:57 moonraker sshd[20089]: debug2: channel 3: rcvd eof
Sep 21 22:19:57 moonraker sshd[20089]: debug2: channel 3: output open -> drain
Sep 21 22:19:57 moonraker sshd[20089]: debug2: channel 3: obuf empty
Sep 21 22:19:57 moonraker sshd[20089]: debug2: channel 3: close_write
Sep 21 22:19:57 moonraker sshd[20089]: debug2: channel 3: output drain -> closed
Sep 21 22:19:57 moonraker sshd[20089]: debug2: channel 3: rcvd close
Sep 21 22:19:57 moonraker sshd[20089]: debug2: channel 3: close_read
Sep 21 22:19:57 moonraker sshd[20089]: debug2: channel 3: input open -> closed
Sep 21 22:19:57 moonraker sshd[20089]: debug2: channel 3: send close
Sep 21 22:19:57 moonraker sshd[20089]: debug2: channel 3: is dead
Sep 21 22:19:57 moonraker sshd[20089]: debug2: channel 3: garbage collecting
Sep 21 22:19:57 moonraker sshd[20089]: debug1: channel 3: free: X11 connection from ::1 port 34632, nchannels 4
```

Any idea what else I should check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the user on your server has a custom `.ssh/rc` file, or you have a non-standard `/etc/ssh/sshrc` file, then the xauth stuff won't get setup correctly.

From the `sshd` man page:

```
 If the file ~/.ssh/rc exists, sh(1) runs it after reading the environment
 files but before starting the user's shell or command.  It must not pro‐
 duce any output on stdout; stderr must be used instead.  If X11 forward‐
 ing is in use, it will receive the "proto cookie" pair in its standard
 input (and DISPLAY in its environment).  The script must call xauth(1)
 because sshd will not run xauth automatically to add X11 cookies.
```

If you need a custom `rc` file, simply add this to it, also from the man page:

```
    if read proto cookie && [ -n "$DISPLAY" ]; then
            if [ `echo $DISPLAY | cut -c1-10` = 'localhost:' ]; then
                    # X11UseLocalhost=yes
                    echo add unix:`echo $DISPLAY |
                        cut -c11-` $proto $cookie
            else
                    # X11UseLocalhost=no
                    echo add $DISPLAY $proto $cookie
            fi | xauth -q -
    fi
```

Comment: I realized that I had a call to `w` in my `sshrc` file. I moved that to my `.bashrc` and this solved the problem. Thanks!

Comment: Wow. Thanks. This was my issue too. I guess this is uncommon enough that no one else thought to mention it.

Comment: What is "a call to w"?

Comment: @tgunr `w` is a command on many Linux distros. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_(Unix))

Comment: Actually, w = who

Answer (score 0):

Checking that the disk is full should be the first step when this error message is encountered.

When the disk is full, *ssh* can not add the key to `.Xauthority`. This causes authentication error.